# Script that detects when there is no action after an amount time in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a question regarding SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

I have two databases that are connected with each other and they exchange information, but for some particular reason it stops working sometimes.

1. Is there a way to find out when there is no more action (nothing written in any table) after 30 minutes?
2. Is there a script that can recognize this and execute another script, that I already have,and that way I don't have to run it manually.
3. It could check the timestamps if the last one was more than 30
   minutes ago?

Thanks anyway
Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SQL AGENT to run a SQL Script that checks your last updated columns; schedule a job that runs every 15 minutes, and if it finds that condition to be true, then execute your next script.